# Way to Propagate Touch Events to Multiple Components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two [React Native Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) components and I'd like one of them to mirror the movements of the other. In other words, if someone scrolls down on the first picker, I'd like the second picker to also scroll down simultaneously.

From a high level, my first thought was to try to propagate the touch events that the first picker is responding to over to the second picker. I noticed that Picker inherits props from View and wondering if there are any callbacks that could be helpful.

Any high level direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is no scrolldown in the picker.Are both of your pickers same?In that case maintain the value in the state and assign to the pickers

Comment: Yes both pickers are the same. That approach would definitely keep the values of the pickers the same, but one would lag behind the other, correct? I'd like the other picker to be synchronized with the first one.

Comment: There would be no lagging as both of them would render again any way